# Possibly wifi problems

Tags: updates, internet

I am connected to a wifi setup from my android phone. i did a ping test and was +ve. but when am updating my OS it shows this:
Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
apt transaction returned result exit-failed

I thought it might be a cmd so I put it on terminal bt turns out its not.
I don't understand the error please help.
My current Os is Ubuntu Budgie 17. and the wifi oftens keeps connecting n disconnecting. Pls help.

After connecting to my wifi, i do this:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

and it displays

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=37 ttl=57 time=70.0ms
```

(the last data keeps changing and it keeps on repeat)
I assume that there is an internet connection now. so I go to 'Software' icon >> Updates >> Install

After some time I get this message :

> Sorry, this did not work
>   Installation of OS updates failed. If the problem persists, contact your software provider .
>   Details
>   Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
>   apt transaction returned result exit-failed

(I thought of this as a command so I put it on terminal) :

```
apt transaction returned result
```

The output was:
E: Invalid operation transaction
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post screenshot(s) demonstrating this?  Also, it would be easier to understand you if you fixed your grammar and added more details to clarify what the problem is here.  Thank you.

Comment: Better than a screenshot is to copy/paste the terminal output which the poster has alluded. Please edit your question and use appropriate markdown while doing so, in this case you'll need to click on the `{}`.

Comment: @Davidyourfriend  which image type does this site support. I tried adding .png and .jpg. Not working.

Comment: @user728627 Most image file types are supported (PNG, JPEG, GIF, etc.).  Links to images are also supported.